# Mobile HTML5 testing

Tags: html, testing, mobile

Can you recommend resources for testing mobile phones against HTML5? I know some resources for testing HTML5:

1. http://www.rng.io/ Ring Mark from FaceBook.
2. http://html5test.com/ from NielsLeenheer (https://github.com/NielsLeenheer/html5test)
3. http://acid3.acidtests.org/ by Ian Hickson (Google)
4. http://test.w3.org/html/tests/approved/ List from W3.org
5. http://mobilehtml5.org/
6. http://www.quirksmode.org/m/ Lots of links to Mobile tests.

I am interesting in security tests and video/audio, CSS3 and Web Forms 2.0 tests.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple I've acknowledged:

- http://css3test.com/
- http://www.css3.info/selectors-test/
- http://quirksmode.org/html5/tests/video.html
- http://double.co.nz/video_test/
- http://www.terrillthompson.com/tests/html5-audio.html